# Can I add a title decoration to a Material Card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

Is there a way to add a title box to a card in the Flutter Material design?  So far I've got to:

```
Card(
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
  ),
  child: ...
)
```

But I can't figure out how to add the title decoration.  Is there a way?  The picture below is roughly what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Card with title box]

Answer (score 0):

In material design the title of a card wouldn't float over the border, as your picture - although it is possible to make, as we see in textFormField decoration.

Below a code of Material 2 for building a card. You can find other examples and how to theme your card in the link: https://material.io/components/cards/flutter#card

```
          Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle),
                  title: const Text('Card title 1'),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    'Secondary Text',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    FlatButton(
                      textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Perform some action
                      },
                      child: const Text('ACTION 1'),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Perform some action
                      },
                      child: const Text('ACTION 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Image.asset('assets/card-sample-image.jpg'),
                Image.asset('assets/card-sample-image-2.jpg'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```